# Большая и малая сцены театра пишутся с прописной или со строчной?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прописная-строчная

> С открытием филиала один из моих любимых спектаклей – «Великий
>   Гэтсби», по произведениям Фицджеральда, – переехал с большой сцены на
>   малую.

На большой сцене работаешь широкими, яркими мазками: каждый твой жест, твоё внутреннее движение, даже твой шёпот должны быть различимы, и далеко – на галёрке. На малой сцене – наоборот: артист должен быть предельно органичен, жизнеподобен, он находится со зрителем практически на равных, только что двигается в свете.

*Жизнеподобен!*

Пожалуйста, предложите что-нибудь взамен жизнеподобию!

Comment: Меня смущает здесь "находится на равных". Поиск в Нацкорпусе дает широкий спектр действий, которые могут производиться на равных, но только не "находиться на равных". Для нашего случая могу предложить "общается со зрителем практически на равных", или говорит, контактирует, в крайнем случае — нейтральное "присутствует".

Comment: Не общается (зритель-то помалкивает), а именно находится!

Comment: Тогда просто "он со зрителем практически на равных" — без бессмысленного глагола "находится". А если "находится", то "в равном положении".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Нет причин, чтобы использовать прописные буквы:** это обычные театральные термины.
А на малой сцене театра "Сатирикон" появится ибсеновская "Гедда Габлер". [Между (2001) // «Известия», 2001.10.21]

2) **Жизнеподобие у артистов встречается,** но ценится по-разному.

Конечно, только в тех случаях, когда зритель ему верит, то есть когда он жизнеподобен. [Семен Лунгин. Виденное наяву (1989-1996)]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E6%E8%E7%ED%E5%EF%EE%E4%EE%E1%E8%E5

Скучное жизнеподобие ― не для этого артиста, у которого в крови, как пузырьки шампанского, «бродит» театральность. [Парадокс Гвоздицкого (2003) // «Театральная жизнь», 2003.04.28]

Answer (score 2):

Большая сцена, малая сцена в одном театре - это же не названия, они пишутся со строчной буквы.

*... артист должен быть предельно органичен, жизнеподобен, он находится со зрителем практически на равных, только что двигается в свете.* Можно заменить на реалистичен (правдив), но можно и так оставить. Жизнеподобные образы – это персонажи, литературные герои, которые во внутреннем мире произведения воспринимаются как реальные, а не условные, мифологические  люди. Смотря что автор имеет в виду.